# I am getting error when i am trying to convert HTML to PDF

Tags: html, ckeditor, jspdf

I used Html to PDF java-script in previous pages it works fine but when I am trying to use it at the page where I am using CKeditor and trying to convert that code to PDF.but somehow I am getting error specialelementhandler is not defined in the console

I am getting an error when I am trying to convert HTML to PDF Getting this error

I am getting error when i am trying to convert HTML to PDF
Getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: specialElementHandlers is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (MailMergeCKEditor:71)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle
```

I want to convert all that text which is in CKeditor to pdf format

```
<head>

    <title>Using placeholders</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="bodyclass">
    <textarea cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" data-sample-short>&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href=&quot;https://ckeditor.com/&quot;&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
<p>
  User Can modify this 
</p>

<m class="a">
  User Can't modify this
</m>


<p>
    User Can modify this
</p>

</textarea>


    <div id="editor"></div>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            extraPlugins: 'placeholder',
            height: 220,
            allowedContent: 'm'






        });
        CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;




        CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (event) {
            if ('placeholder' == event.data.name) {
                var input = event.data.definition.getContents('info').get('name');
                input.type = 'select';
                input.items = [['Company'], ['Email'], ['First Name'], ['Last Name']];
                input.setup = function () {
                    this.setValue('Company');
                };
            }
        });


 var doc = new jsPDF();

$('#cmd').click(function () {   
    doc.fromHTML($('#bodyclass').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});



    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Know this is a but old, but did you ever figure this out? Thought I would ask before asking a new question and getting referred back here:)

Comment: You can use jspdf  https://www.codexworld.com/convert-html-to-pdf-using-javascript-jspdf/

Comment: Thanks @ZCoder, that is a good tutorial (and site). Looking to use CKeditor but the codexworld helps:)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you haven't assigned anything to the `specialElementHandlers` variable.

Just after your `var doc = new jsPDF();` statement you need to add the below block,

```
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor1': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

After adding this, try refreshing the page, hope your issue will get resolved.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @David now i am getting this error Uncaught The editor instance "editor1" is already attached to the provided element.

Comment: In that case change `'#editor'` as `'#editor1' (in my answer) and try again.